# Json objects to Array of objects in android

Tags: android, json, jackson

I want map each object in CoinPriceMulti class into an Array of Objects so I don't need to do like getBTC().getUSD(), getETH().getUSD() and getUSD().getUSD() for each object I just want to all in array of Objects so i can do object[0].getUSD() like this.

This is my entity class for the given JSON response below

```
public class CoinPriceMulti {

/**
 * BTC : {"USD":7167.06}
 * ETH : {"USD":182.63}
 * USD : {"USD":1}
 */

private BTCBean BTC;
private ETHBean ETH;
private USDBean USD;

public BTCBean getBTC() {
    return BTC;
}

public void setBTC(BTCBean BTC) {
    this.BTC = BTC;
}

public ETHBean getETH() {
    return ETH;
}

public void setETH(ETHBean ETH) {
    this.ETH = ETH;
}

public USDBean getUSD() {
    return USD;
}

public void setUSD(USDBean USD) {
    this.USD = USD;
}

public static class BTCBean {
    /**
     * USD : 7167.06
     */

    private double USD;

    public double getUSD() {
        return USD;
    }

    public void setUSD(double USD) {
        this.USD = USD;
    }
}

public static class ETHBean {
    /**
     * USD : 182.63
     */

    private double USD;

    public double getUSD() {
        return USD;
    }

    public void setUSD(double USD) {
        this.USD = USD;
    }
}

public static class USDBean {
    /**
     * USD : 1
     */

    private int USD;

    public int getUSD() {
        return USD;
    }

    public void setUSD(int USD) {
        this.USD = USD;
    }
}
```

This is my JSON response

```
{
"BTC": {
    "USD": 7167.06
},
"ETH": {
    "USD": 182.63
},
"USD": {
    "USD": 1
}
```

}

I want to map each BTC, ETH and USD into an array, not separate objects I want to traverse through each

Answer (score 0):

If possible then, convert or get your response converted as below

```
{
"result": [
"BTC": {
  "USD": 7167.06
},
"ETH": {
  "USD": 182.63
},
"USD": {
  "USD": 1
}]
}
```

Comment: It is api response how can i change it

Comment: the person who made this api can help on this !

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON contains dynamic field names, we can try like this

1. Create a simple POJO to read price in `USD`

   ```
   class MarketValue {
       @SerializedName("USD")
       Double usd;
   }
   ```
2. Create token type for `Gson` parsing

   ```
   Type typeToken = new TypeToken<Map<String, MarketValue>>() {}.getType();
   ```
3. Parse JSON using `Gson` parser

   ```
   Map<String, MarketValue> result = new Gson().fromJson(/* Your JSON string */, typeToken);
   ```

You can easily covert map to a list of object and access using index. I have used `Gson` for parsing but you do get the idea how we parse the JSON.

Comment: I am not getting things clearly please help it's better if you ping me my contact number 7878049434 @Hussain